# VB.Net Instagram Webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, instagram, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyname

I can't seem to find a way to input my text from my textbox's to anything on Instagram, they don't have id's and I can't seem to get the getbytagname to put the information in one of the inputs such as username it goes in all of them.

Anyone got any guides or even the code on how to input text into Instagram?

I have tried,
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElemen‌​tsByName("class=" = "kp5f7 _qy55y").Item("value").SetAttribute("value", texbox1.text )

but with no luck

Comment: Please check how to ask a proper question [ask]

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a forum for general advice, please provide a specific problem and code that you have already tried to implement.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried the following with no success.

 Dim Nameatt = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("class=" = "kp5f7 _qy55y").Item("value").SetAttribute("value", texbox1.text )

Comment: `("class=" = "kp5f7 _qy55y")` is an evaluation and will result in `False` since the two strings are not equal. Use `getElementsByClassName()` and specify either `kp5f7` or `_qy55y`.

Answer (score -1):

Class name, in your specific case (`kp5f7 _qy55y`), seems random-generated. Are you sure that each session produces that particular class name?

Comment: I checked with 2 different computers and both gave back the same class so I assume it's not random

Comment: Okay just found that 4 other elements on the webpage have the same class name but different placeholder names